# How do I customize Ubuntu Server's terminal preferences?

Tags: server

I installed Ubuntu Server. First time Server user. I'm not sure how to customize the terminal, since there is no GUI menu. How do I go about changing things like font and background/foreground colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better answer out there somewhere, but you can use `setterm` to set things like color (`-foreground <color>`, `-background <color>`, etc), and `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to change things like font and character set.

Note: The `setterm` commands will only apply to the current shell process, so you'll probably want to put those in a file that gets executed every time you start the shell, like `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That does it. Just not nearly as many options as I was hoping for. I wanted to use a hex color code.

Comment: Putting `setterm --background black --foreground red` into ~/.bashrc works well enough.

Comment: Unfortunately most terminals don't seem to support hex color codes. For a bit more control you could use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) like `echo -e "\e[38;5;82m"`, though the syntax is really weird.

Comment: I finally got SSH going to log into my server remotely, not requiring the server terminal directly. I guess that's really the way to do it with servers. So, the terminal colors are irrelevant if I'm using my main editor/terminal anyway.